# Modelisation of an automaton with coq

Tags: logic, coq, automaton

i have a problem with definition of an automaton in coq proof assisstant, an error was shown when i create this code:

```
(*automate*)

Record automaton :Type:=
mk_auto {
   states : Set;
   actions :Set;
   initial : states;
   transitions : states -> actions -> list states
}.
(*States*)
Inductive st :Set:= q0 | q1 |q2 .
Inductive acts:Set:=pred(p:nat)|event(e:bool).
Definition a :acts:=pred(0).
Definition b:acts:=pred(1).
Definition c:acts:=event(true).
Function trans (q:st)(x:acts) :list st :=
match q, x with
  | q0, a =>  cons q1 nil
  | q1, b =>  cons q0 nil
  | q1, c =>  cons q2 nil
  | _,_ =>    nil (A:=_)
end.
```

the error was: 
Error: This clause is redundant. (underlined this clause " | q1, c =>  cons q2 nil")

Thanks for your attentions.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform pattern matching, you have two possibilities in the pattern: constructors or free variables that act like binders.
For example, the first case of your match read as ''if `q` has been constructed with `q0`, and for any value of `x` that will be named `a` in the branch, do ...'''

There is no relation between the `a` in this branch and the definition `Definition a` you made before.

Therefore, the 2nd and 3rd lines are redundant, they both catch the case where `q` has been constructed with `q1` and `x` has any value.

I guess you wanted write something like:

```
match q, x with
  | q0, pred 0 => cons q1 nil
  | q1, pred 1 => cons q0 nil
  | q1, event true => cons q2 nil
  | _, _ => nil (A := _)
end.
```

You can make aliases using `Definition` in a pattern matching branch. To my knowledge, the only way to do such an alias is to use `Notation`.

If you replace the definitions of `a` `b` and `c` by:

```
Notation "'a'" := (pred 0).
Notation "'b'" := (pred 1).
Notation "'c'" := (event true).
```

then your code will behave like (I think) you intended. I advise you to read [this](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#sec511) part of Coq's Manual to learn about notations.

Best,
V.